# Filter Timeseries Data Using Sunrise and Sunset Times

Tags: r, lubridate, tidy

I'm trying to subset data that falls between sunset and sunrise.
The data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(suncalc)

dat <- tibble(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct('2020-08-03 00:00:00'), 
                             as.POSIXct('2020-08-09 12:00:00'), 
                             by=3600),
              var1 = rnorm(157,2,1),
              var2 = rnorm(157,3,5)) %>% 
  mutate(getSunlightTimes(date = as.Date(datetime, format = '%m/%d/%Y'),
                         lat = 43.1, lon = -76.2, tz = 'America/New_York',
                         keep = c('sunrise', 'sunset'))) %>% 
  select(c(datetime, var1, var2, sunrise, sunset))
```

Then I would like to subset the data so that I only retain rows where `datetime` falls between sunrise and sunset on a given day. I tried:

```
myrange <- as.interval(unique(dat$sunrise), unique(dat$sunset))

dat <- dat %>% 
  filter(datetime %within% myrange)
```

This compiles but throws warnings and does not include all the rows of data that it should. Thanks in advance.

Comment: the tibble you're trying to generate doesn't work, you call `dat` before you assign it. if the structure of the tibble has a sunrise and sunset column for each row can't you just do `filter(datetime > sunrise & datetime < sunset)`?

Comment: @EJJ, try replacing that with 157 (the length of the `seq` above them).

Comment: @r2evans right, makes sense

Comment: Apologies, updated to use 157 (I already had `dat` in my environment so it didn't throw the error...rookie mistake)

Comment: @EJJ you are right! Was making this way too hard....in my case I'm trying to pull out data that falls between sunset and sunrise though so I needed to use `filter(datetime < sunrise | datetime > sunset)` otherwise the result is no data left (can't have times that fall before sunrise and also after sunset on a given day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

First, create a partial `dat`. I'll add `date`, since we need it both for the calculations and for joining the data back in.

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- tibble(datetime = seq(as.POSIXct('2020-08-03 00:00:00'), 
                             as.POSIXct('2020-08-09 12:00:00'), 
                             by=3600),
              var1 = rnorm(157,2,1),
              var2 = rnorm(157,3,5)) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(datetime))
dat
# # A tibble: 157 x 4
#    datetime             var1   var2 date      
#    <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl> <date>    
#  1 2020-08-03 00:00:00  3.37 -1.00  2020-08-03
#  2 2020-08-03 01:00:00  1.44  0.333 2020-08-03
#  3 2020-08-03 02:00:00  2.36  9.44  2020-08-03
#  4 2020-08-03 03:00:00  2.63  2.12  2020-08-03
#  5 2020-08-03 04:00:00  2.40 -2.36  2020-08-03
#  6 2020-08-03 05:00:00  1.89  3.82  2020-08-03
#  7 2020-08-03 06:00:00  3.51  1.19  2020-08-03
#  8 2020-08-03 07:00:00  1.91  5.95  2020-08-03
#  9 2020-08-03 08:00:00  4.02 10.2   2020-08-03
# 10 2020-08-03 09:00:00  1.94 -1.96  2020-08-03
# # ... with 147 more rows
```

Now reduce that to the distinct `date`s found, get the sunrise/sunset for those dates, and join back in to the original `dat` (with `left_join`). After that, we can `filter` the times we need.

```r
distinct(dat, date) %>%
  with(., getSunlightTimes(date = date,
                           lat = 43.1, lon = -76.2, tz = 'America/New_York',
                           keep = c('sunrise', 'sunset'))) %>% 
  left_join(dat, ., by = "date") %>%
  filter(sunrise <= datetime, datetime <= sunset)
# # A tibble: 85 x 8
#    datetime             var1  var2 date         lat   lon sunrise             sunset             
#    <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>             
#  1 2020-08-03 06:00:00 3.51   1.19 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  2 2020-08-03 07:00:00 1.91   5.95 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  3 2020-08-03 08:00:00 4.02  10.2  2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  4 2020-08-03 09:00:00 1.94  -1.96 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  5 2020-08-03 10:00:00 3.30   5.27 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  6 2020-08-03 11:00:00 4.29   3.42 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  7 2020-08-03 12:00:00 0.611  7.48 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  8 2020-08-03 13:00:00 1.72   1.85 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
#  9 2020-08-03 14:00:00 1.87   7.18 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
# 10 2020-08-03 15:00:00 2.64  -5.73 2020-08-03  43.1 -76.2 2020-08-03 05:59:13 2020-08-03 20:25:11
# # ... with 75 more rows
```

Note that we cannot use `dplyr::between` here, since that function only uses the first of its `left` and `right` arguments.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the use of the period in `with(., getSunlightTimes(date = date,
                           lat = 43.1, lon = -76.2, tz = 'America/New_York',
                           keep = c('sunrise', 'sunset')))` ? Also why is it necessary to call back to `dat` when you perform the `left_join` since it's still within a pipeline?

Comment: It's one way to use `%>%`-pipe data with normal R functions. I could have saved `d <- distinct(dat, date); getSunlightTimes(date = d$date, ...)` instead, but I find the `with(., ...)` trick a little more flowing.

Comment: If you look at the results from `with(., getSunlightTimes(...))`, it does not have the original `dat` in it. I suggest you go through this step-by-step: first do `distinct(...)` and see what it gives you; in this case, it's only 7 rows despite `dat` having 157 rows. Then the return value from `with(...)` is ... also 7 rows. From there, we `left_join` the original data *back* into this pipe, so now we have the original `dat` augmented with the sunrise/sunset fields. All 157 rows. And then we `filter` it down to 75 rows. Step-by-step helps understand what each step is doing.